# How do tension and linear density affect speed of waves in spring? (Qualitative)

Tags: forces, waves, spring

Wave speed, tension and linear density (mass per unit length) can be related by the following equation:

$$v=\sqrt{\frac{T}{\mu}}$$

The derivation of the equation could be done by using calculus.
I know that greater tension or smaller linear density would result in greater wave speed. However, how could we understand the relation **qualitatively** (without maths)?

**My thoughts:**

Let $x$ direction and $y$ direction be the directions of wave propagation and particles motion respectively.

1. The component of tension in $y$ direction affects the acceleration of a particle towards its equilibrium position. Greater tension means greater acceleration of particles, which means greater speed of particles and thus greater wave speed.
2. Greater linear density means greater mass within a length. Greater mass means greater inertia so it is harder to change its motion. As a result, the wave propagates slower.

Comment: I think you have answered your own question. Can you clarify (at least for me) what else do you want to understand about the equation "qualitatively" ?

Comment: I am not sure do my thoughts make sense. I would like to understand the relation between wave speed, tension and linear density in terms of particles. Thanks!

Comment: very good question